# Querying Firebase database but not getting data or errors

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, querying

I am creating a HTML page where a user can view all of their posts and edit them. At the moment I am just console logging the result to see if I get the desired data but I'm not receiving any errors or data.

The page should display only currently signed in user's posts but my code below isn't returning anything even though there are posts for that user in the Firebase database.

Any idea on how to only show the post for the currently signed in user?

Here is how my data is set up:

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-KnP3MkFt5559uP1w5fh" : {
      "content" : "content 1",
      "title" : "title 1",
      "uid" : "O96P2INZn6S42dqqwgtz2OfgmYb2"
    },
    "-KnPPwHhfXDv34Lr0HMP" : {
      "content" : "content 2",
      "title" : "title 2",
      "uid" : "B3nHbd7G49Y2iwSA3tJSaHFVuCq2"
    },
    "-KnPR_ZsgOwrpRDGZkHT" : {
      "content" : "content 3",
      "title" : "title 3",
      "uid" : "O96P2INZn6S42dqqwgtz2OfgmYb2"
    }
  },
  "profiles" : {
    "B3nHbd7G49Y2iwSA3tJSaHFVuCq2" : {
      "email" : "-",
      "firstName" : "-",
      "lastName" : "-"
    },
    "O96P2INZn6S42dqqwgtz2OfgmYb2" : {
      "email" : "-",
      "firstName" : "firstFirst",
      "lastName" : "firstLast"
    }
  },
  "user-posts" : {
    "-KnP3MkFt5559uP1w5fh" : {
      "content" : "content 1",
      "title" : "title 1",
      "uid" : "O96P2INZn6S42dqqwgtz2OfgmYb2"
    },
    "-KnPPwHhfXDv34Lr0HMP" : {
      "content" : "content 2",
      "title" : "title 2",
      "uid" : "B3nHbd7G49Y2iwSA3tJSaHFVuCq2"
    },
    "-KnPR_ZsgOwrpRDGZkHT" : {
      "content" : "content 3",
      "title" : "title 3",
      "uid" : "O96P2INZn6S42dqqwgtz2OfgmYb2"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my javascript:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
    if (firebaseUser) {
var userid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var myPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('user-posts');

    myPostsRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo('userid').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        var myPostData = snapshot.val();

        console.log(myPostData); 

    });
});
```

Comment: Well you are not catching any errors, so you wouldn't see them. The functions `onAuthStateChanged` and `on('child_added'` will both return an error callback, if you add something like  `.catch(function(error) { console.log(error)}` you should see errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`myPostsRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo('userid')`

..looks like it should be this:

`myPostsRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userid)`

Happens all the time :)

Comment: Thanks @pejalo & edzillion. It's working now. I also had to change this:                 myPostsRef.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) { 
var myPostData = childSnapshot.val();  // changed from snapshot
console.log(myPostData);
});